# Ignored ThenInclude statement on generating query expression EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

**Foreword:**

I have 2 projects on .NET Core 3.1, one EF Core 3.1.17 and another on 5.0.10 and in both I've used Include/ThenInclude the same way and all works good.
Now I'm trying upgrade my project on 3.1.17 to version 5.0.10 and got some weird situation.

**Problem:**

When I'm trying to use ThenInclude statement in expression all entities in ThenInclude are ignoring when EF generate a query.

It's my expression:

```
var settings = await _dbRepository.GetRegionRoles(systemId)
            .Include(r => r.Region)
            .Include(sr => sr.SystemRole)
            .ThenInclude(ro => ro.Role)
            .Include(gs => gs.GroupSettings)
            .Where(w => w.GroupSettings.Any())
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

And EF recognize all ThenInclude statement before generating query(I tried to add some more where it's possible and got the same result), there is trace log:

```
 Compiling query expression: 
'DbSet<RegionRole>()
    .Include(x => x.SystemRole)
    .Where(w => w.SystemRole.SystemId.Equals((int)__systemId_0))
    .Include(r => r.Region)
    .Include(sr => sr.SystemRole)
    .ThenInclude(ro => ro.Role)
    .Include(gs => gs.GroupSettings)
    .Include(sr => sr.SystemRole)
    .ThenInclude(s => s.SystemCode)
    .Where(w => w.GroupSettings
        .Any())'
```

But result of generation looks like:

```
Generated query execution expression: 
'queryContext => new SingleQueryingEnumerable<RegionRole>(
    (RelationalQueryContext)queryContext, 
    RelationalCommandCache.SelectExpression(
        Projection Mapping:
        SELECT r.Id, r.CreatedByUser, r.CreatedDate //... and many other fields from each table
        FROM Main.RegionRole AS r
        INNER JOIN Main.SystemRole AS s ON r.SystemRoleId == s.Id
        INNER JOIN Main.Region AS r0 ON r.RegionId == r0.Id
        LEFT JOIN Main.GroupSettings AS g ON r.Id == g.RegionRoleId
        WHERE (s.SystemId == CAST(@__systemId_0) AS int)) && EXISTS (
            Projection Mapping:
            SELECT 1
            FROM Main.GroupSettings AS g0
            WHERE (r.Id != NULL) && (r.Id == g0.RegionRoleId))
        ORDER BY r.Id ASC, s.Id ASC, r0.Id ASC, g.Id ASC), 
    Func<QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator, RegionRole>, 
    K2Project.BE.DAL.Models.K2DbContext, 
    False, 
    False
)'
```

So as we can see here, entity "Role" that is in ThenInclude statement is missing in result.

All entities has navigation properties and described in fluent api. All tables have foreign keys.

There is an example of entity "SystemRole"

```
public class SystemRole
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }        

    #region Dependencies

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    #endregion
 }
```

And fluent api:

```
public class SystemRoleEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SystemRole>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SystemRole> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(SystemRole), DbConst.MainSchemaName);

        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWSEQUENTIALID()");

        builder.HasOne(p => p.Role)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.RoleId)
            .IsRequired(true);

    }
}
```

**Question:**

What is difference between usage of ThenInclude in EF Core version 3.1.17 and 5.0.10 and why the same expression works on first version but don't works on another? Maybe I did something wrong or forget to change something when changed the framework version?

P.S. In my second project that was from beginning on EF Core 5.0.10 all expressions with Include/ThenInclude statements doing great.

Comment: Please post this as a [mre] so we can reproduce it and possibly fix it. So far, this looks like a bug but maybe you overlooked something.

Comment: Idk how to exclude this part, it's strong integrated custom role model in very big project with a lot of relations. Maybe I can post just a small example of entity models used in my expression and mb a mvp of startup? Will it be OK?

Comment: As long as we have a model that reproduces the problem, yes. If we can't fix/explain it then that would be the basis for a bug report.

Comment: there is some models, fluent api, dbcontext, repository, service and startup [link to github](https://github.com/AlexGrynjuk/ignore-ThenInclude-statement-on-generating-query-expression-EF-Core-MRE) hope it's enough

Comment: as a reminder: project was created on .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.1.17 and then changed EF Core version to 5.0.10. On another branch where is still version 3.1.17 all works good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That shows why it's important to include all code in questions.

This is the `GetRegionRoles` method :

```cs
public IQueryable<RegionRole> GetRegionRoles(SystemCodesEnum systemId)
{
    return _context.RegionRole
        .Include(x => x.SystemRole)
        .Where(w => w.SystemRole.SystemId.Equals((int)systemId));
}
```

So it already contains an `Include` and the same `Include` is repeated in your query:

```cs
var settings = await _dbRepository.GetRegionRoles(systemId)
            .Include(r => r.Region)
            .Include(sr => sr.SystemRole) // <= here
                .ThenInclude(ro => ro.Role)
            .Include(gs => gs.GroupSettings)
            .Where(w => w.GroupSettings.Any())
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

When I reproduce this code I see that, apparently, EF is sensitive to placement of `Include` statements. In this case the similar Includes are separated by a `Where` statement. Somehow that causes EF (core 5) to ignore the repeated `Include` (followed by `ThenInclude`). It works if you remove the separation, simply by moving the `Where` statement:

```cs
public IQueryable<RegionRole> GetRegionRoles(SystemCodesEnum systemId)
{
    return _context.RegionRole
        .Where(w => w.SystemRole.SystemId.Equals((int)systemId))
        .Include(x => x.SystemRole);
}
```

I assume this is not intended behavior (why would it?). You may want to post a bug report, or see if it still happens in version 6.

Comment: In retrospect, the trace log also shows how the entire expression was built, but far less conspicuous.

Comment: thanks! It's a little strange behavior and what is more strange that it works on prev version... But if I want to include "Role" and "SystemCode" after "System role", as I know, it must looks something like this: `.Include(sr => sr.SystemRole).ThenInclude(ro => ro.Role).Include(sr => sr.SystemRole).ThenInclude(sc => sc.SystemCode)` and if I put Where statement between this includes then second one will not work?

Comment: In that case the first Include carries the ThenInclude with it. I think you have to decide what to do with repository methods like that, maybe parametrize the Includes.

Comment: I just rewrote my expression without `Where` in first method and it works. Thank you for advice! But it's still strange behavior of EF. Now I will try to upgrade to version 6 and look if it still work the same way and if it do - will make a bug request. Thanks again.